# Can I choose where my conda environment is stored?

Tags: conda

Can I change the path /Users/nolan/miniconda/envs/ to another one when creating a virtual environment ? I'd like it to be specific to my project directory. (As we can do with virtualenv)

```
$conda info -e
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
# conda environments:
#
_build                   /Users/nolan/miniconda/envs/_build
myen3                    /Users/nolan/miniconda/envs/myen3
nolanemirot              /Users/nolan/miniconda/envs/nolanemirot
root                  *  /Users/nolan/miniconda
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can change the environments directory by editing your .condarc file found in your user directory. Add the following specifying the path to the directory you want:

```
envs_dirs:
  - /Users/nolan/newpath
```

Comment: Can we specify folders at env level? I mean, each env in a different folder

Comment: When you specify an environment directory this is where conda will create the actual environment subdirectories. So what ever you specify as the base envs_dirs it will make a directory in that for each environment you create. I don't know that there is a way to specify entirely different base directory paths for different environments. Here is the documentation on this, https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-environment-directories-envs-dirs

Answer (score 18):

If you would like it to be relative to your project directory, use the `--prefix` flag: https://conda.io/docs/commands/env/conda-env-create.html?highlight=prefix

For example, if you use `environment.yml` files to define your environment and you want your environment to be created in the `venv` directory of your project you would use the following:

`conda env create -f environment.yml --prefix venv`

The `conda create` command also has the `--prefix` flag as well: https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-create.html?highlight=prefix

I don't know if this was available as of the original posting, but it should be available as of Liu Sha's comment, and gets closer to answering the question in regards to "I'd like it to be specific to my project directory".

Comment: The links are not more valid, but I think this is a good substitute: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#specifying-a-location-for-an-environment

Answer (score 16):

If you need a one-liner instead of searching for your `.condarc` file, you can use the following command:

`conda config --add envs_dirs /Users/nolan/newpath`

Answer (score 10):

`conda create -p env-dir` is the possible solution which i used where **venv**, **virtualenv** and even **pipenv** failed as I used berrycomda on my raspberrypi

Answer (score 1):

You can also configure this via an environment variable `CONDA_ENVS_PATH`. I found this useful when configuring the location for all users on a system by adding the following to `/etc/bashrc`:

```
export CONDA_ENVS_PATH="$HOME/.conda/envs/"
```