# Specify conda env in project folder

Tags: anaconda, conda, miniconda

I want to dynamically store in the project directory, how can I do that?
I have searching and found this [Can I choose where my conda environment is stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280479/can-i-choose-where-my-conda-environment-is-stored) but this not dynamically store my conda environment to the project directory like virtualenv do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a post activate script in Conda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34606196/create-a-post-activate-script-in-conda)

Answer (score 5):

Use `--prefix, -p` for `conda create` instead of `--name, -n`.

```sh
$ conda create --help
...
Target Environment Specification:
  -n ENVIRONMENT, --name ENVIRONMENT
                        Name of environment.
  -p PATH, --prefix PATH
                        Full path to environment location (i.e. prefix).
...
```

#### Usage

```sh
conda create -p ./venv python=3.6
conda env list

# activate the local environment with relative or absolute path
conda activate ./venv
conda deactivate

# remove the env
conda env remove -p ./venv
# or just delete the "venv" folder directly
```

**Note**: When you set a specific path for your environment with `-p`, `-n` is not allowed, which means you cannot give the env a name in this case. You have to operate this kind of envs with their **paths**.