# Wrong env path in Conda

Tags: python, path, conda

When I list my `conda` environments:

```
$ conda env list
# conda environments:
#
cardio4                  /home/username/.conda/envs/cardio4
minimal                  /home/username/.conda/envs/minimal
py2                      /home/username/.conda/envs/py2
py37                     /home/username/.conda/envs/py37
vmtk                  *  /home/username/.conda/envs/vmtk
base                     /opt/anaconda3
```

but when I try to install new environment:

```
$ conda create -n test python=3.7
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /opt/anaconda3/envs/test
```

Why is the default environment location not in my home .conda directory? This issue messes up some other stuff, like `pip`, which is not invoked from the correct location (i.e. my env location). Is there any PATH I can set to tell `conda` where my envs are?

This is confusing because `conda activate` actually does work and I can use these environments.

My `.condarc`:

```
env_dirs:
  - ~/.conda/envs
  - /opt/anaconda3/envs
```

`/opt` path is lower in list, yet it's somehow prioritized.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280479/can-i-choose-where-my-conda-environment-is-stored

Comment: @cel I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a typo in your `.condarc` file.  The correct key name is `envs_dirs` (note both `s` characters).  With that change, `conda create` should work as you expect.

```
envs_dirs:
  - ~/.conda/envs
  - /opt/anaconda3/envs
```

Comment: No kidding.  I spent more time than I would like to admit trying to figure out why your simple example didn't work on my machine, either...  I was inserting print statements into the conda code base, and even contemplating filing a bug with the conda repo. Then... oh, duh.  I guess I was desperate to procrastinate on my real work.  Lucky you. :-)