# Does installing Anaconda on D drive save conda envs on D drive? Or are they still stored in C drive?

Tags: memory, installation, anaconda, conda, reinstall

I have a lot of conda envs in my `C:\Users\username\.conda\envs` directory. I have been facing a lot of memory issues due to this. I was planing on doing a complete reinstall of Anaconda in my `D` drive. But I wanted to confirm that this would actually create `envs` in my `D` drive and not in my `C` drive.

Also, if it does create `envs` in `D` then does copy-pasting the environment folders from `C:\Users\username\.conda\envs` into the newly created `envs` successfully restore my conda envs?

Comment: I have ~44 envs

Comment: There is a `env_dirs` configuration variable in `.condarc` that you may want to have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280479/can-i-choose-where-my-conda-environment-is-stored
Generally moving environments by moving the folders will lead to problems (e.g. scripts may not find the python interpreter). Exporting to a yaml file and reinstalling however may work fine. I would for sure make a backup before trying this tho.

Comment: @cel will reinstalling in D put the envs in D?

Comment: I think so, if not you can always choose a location of choice by setting the `env_dirs` variable.

Comment: I think you need to specify both the `envs_dirs` and the `pkgs_dirs`. See `conda config --describe pkgs_dirs envs_dirs`. As long as they're on the same drive, then hardlinking will work (maximizing space saving). I'm not on Windows, so I can't confirm the installation behavior. Also, I'd recommend install Miniconda as your **base**, instead of Anaconda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Anaconda docs: Moving Anaconda from one directory to another](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/move-directory/):

> Anaconda environment management requires known paths, and Anaconda
> must know the exact path where it is installed at installation time.
>
> If you simply copy the Anaconda files to a new directory, Anaconda
> will not work.
>
> To move Anaconda from one directory to another:
>
> OPTIONAL: Save your environments using the conda managing environments
> instructions.
>
> 1. Uninstall Anaconda.
> 2. Go to the new directory and install
>    it there following the Anaconda installation instructions.
>
> OPTIONAL:
> Restore your environments using the conda managing environments
> instructions.