# Looking for compiled version of R 4.0.3 for CentOS Linux

Tags: r, linux, centos

I am new to this.  I was asked to install R version 4.0.3.   I was able to download but that requires me to compile.  Just checking is there ready made package which I can download and install.  Greatly appreciate any help.   Thank you so much.

I will be installing this on CentOS 6 and CentOS 7 server.

Comment: Hi, have you consider use `Docker`? With Docker you just pull the container `docker pull r-base:4.0.3` and you are ready to use the image.

Comment: welcome, its better to ask this question in https://www.superuser.com

Comment: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/redhat/

Answer (score 2):

Use [`conda`](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/) package manager:

```
# find package 'r-essentials':
conda search r-essentials

# Create environment named 'r' and install package 'r-essentials' there:
conda create -n r r-essentials

# Use it:
conda activate r-essentials
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply. 
I am following as per your above steps, when I do that, it's keep installing in / file system.  How do I change the location to I want. It's trying to install under /root/conda/pkgs

Comment: @Sammy Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35280479/967621